# Networking issues, possible to resolve with async method?

Tags: c#, networking, asynchronous, console-application, lidgren

I am learning to use the networking library Lidgren. I have tried to get a basic client/setup server going but I am getting an error thrown at me. So far I just have the server, when I run it the serve runs for maybe 10 seconds then crashes with an exception of `Lidgren.Network.NetException`. This does not happen if I remove the first `while` loop, which is intended to keep checking for messages. The additional information on the exception is this: `Additional information: Trying to read past the buffer size - likely caused by mismatching Write/Reads, different size or order.`

Can anyone help me with this?
Also, is it likely I can avoid this by trying to read the messages asynchronously and how would I do this if so?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Lidgren.Network;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetPeerConfiguration config = new NetPeerConfiguration("MyExampleName");
            config.Port = 14242;

            NetServer server = new NetServer(config);
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server Started...");

            bool listen = true;
            while (listen)
            {
                NetIncomingMessage msg;
                while ((msg = server.ReadMessage()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Started Listening...");
                    switch (msg.MessageType)
                    {
                        case NetIncomingMessageType.VerboseDebugMessage:
                        case NetIncomingMessageType.DebugMessage:
                        case NetIncomingMessageType.WarningMessage:
                        case NetIncomingMessageType.Data:
                            if (msg.ReadString() == "bye")
                            {
                                listen = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(msg.ReadString());
                            }
                            break;
                        case NetIncomingMessageType.ErrorMessage:
                            Console.WriteLine(msg.ReadString());
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Unhandled type: " + msg.MessageType);
                            break;
                    }
                    server.Recycle(msg);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Finished Listening!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means you are not reading the same data types in the same order as you sent them. It looks like the code above reads a string - what do you send? Also, you should call server.Shutdown() when exiting your loop.